# Can I use the plural form when stating the possession of just one item?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, possessives

If I want to say I have something without emphasis on the quantity, are both of these sentences ok?

1. I have an apple.
2. I have apples. (I may just have one apple.)

Comment: If you only have one apple, it would be incorrect to say 'I have apples'. However if you had more than one it would still be correct to say 'I have an apple'. You would be telling the truth, but you might need to be careful if you were saying it under oath, where you had sworn to *tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth*. If the fact of your having more than one apple, were deemed significant, and put an entirely different slant on your evidence, you might be guilty of perjury, for not having told *the whole truth*.

Comment: Thank you very much. That sounds so terrible. I'll be more careful right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WS2 said, if you have only one apple, it would generally be considered incorrect and a lie to say "I have apples."

I can only think of one kind of context where people might use a plural for this kind of object and intend it to allow a singular interpretation. This is in sentences referring to indefinite people and indefinite objects.

Here are two examples of what I mean that I found using a Google search for "person found to possess":

> Under the Films Act, anyone making or reproducing obscene films can be
>   fined up to $40,000 and jailed up to two years.
>
> For distributing obscene films, a person can be fined up to $80,000
>   and jailed up to a year.
>
> A person found to possess obscene films can be fined up to $20,000 and
>   jailed up to six months.

– [news.asiaone.com, 'Humiliating to have modesty peddled by perverts'](http://news.asiaone.com/news/singapore/humiliating-have-modesty-peddled-perverts)

I assume the law mentioned in this article also makes it illegal to produce or possess a single obscene film.

> Any person found to possess or be under the influence of illegal
>   substances will be expelled from the retreat with no refunds given.

– [International Brotherhood Retreats](http://www.brotherhoodretreats.com/faq.htm)

I doubt that you can stay or get a refund if you only possess one illegal substance.

So in contexts like these, if your'e *interpreting* something someone else has written, I'd say you should be careful: it's not necessarily safe to assume the singular interpretation is excluded. But if you're *writing,* I would say it's better to use the singular in these contexts. This reduces ambiguity, which is usually a good thing if you're describing rules, as these examples do. To really make it clear, it might be necessary to list both options, along the lines of  "a person found to possess an obscene film or multiple obscene films...." I'd imagine lawyers have designed some way to express this idea unambiguously, or some kind of rule for interpreting the wording of legal documents in these contexts.

Comment: In a store: -Do you have bananas? -Yes, we have bananas. -Give me three bananas, please. -We only have one left.